# Google Drive: Setting the Preview Thumbnail

Tags: preview, google-drive-api

Videos, Spreadsheets and Docs support previewing their content in Drive. I'm developing a Google Drive application and I'd like it to support previewing its contents so are there any api's in Google drive to set the preview thumbnail image or embedding in it something? For example in video clicking preview it shows the video in a player and previewing an image or spreadsheet shows a snapshot of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not currently possible, but something we want to provide with the API. It is not so straighforward as it sounds, as there are issues with versions, sharing, etc.