# How can I preview my documents on Google Drive using PHP SDK?

Tags: php, google-drive-api, symfony, preview

I have a custom CMS where clients upload documents of different types. Now they want to see the document contents before they decide to download it, just like we do in Google Drive. 
My question is how can I use Google Drive PHP SDK to allow my users to preview documents? When user clicks on Preview button in CMS, I immediate upload the document to my Google Drive, from there I want to create a preview and show it to the User. 
I am aware of ViewersJs and Google Doc Viewer but its not providing solution for all types of documents.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no function from the API that will do what you want based from this so posts - [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28413716/5995040) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11813222/5995040). But there is a related [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10479239/5995040) that discussed about previewing documents using the exportlink to pdf (public documents). You can also try and take a look on embedlink. Hope this helps.